# trying to solve palindrome integer in python 3 code is working but giving wrong output

Tags: numbers, palindrome

```
enter code here''' class Solution:
def isPalindrome(self, x: int) -> bool:
    x = str(x)
    lst = list(x)
    str_val = []
    count = len(lst)
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        str_val.append(lst[count-1])
        count -= 1
    value = [str(i) for i in str_val]
    res = int("".join(value))
    
    if int(res) == x:
        return True
    else:
        return False
        
  '''
```

*trying to solve palindrome integer in python 3 code is working but giving wrong output.*

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to check for integers only, you can try the below code. It's a two pointer approach.

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, x: int) -> bool:
        x = str(x)
        if len(x) < 2: return True
        
        s, e = 0, len(x)-1
        
        while s < e:
            if x[s] != x[e]: return False
            s += 1
            e -= 1
        return True
```

You can also do this in one line in python to check if a number (as a string) and it's reverse is same or not.

```
str(x) == str(x)[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your results are not as expected is due to the type change that you make in the first line of your function.

```
x = str(x)
```

It is necessary to convert x into a string so that you can iterate over it and put it into a list for your second line of code:

```
lst = list(x)
```

but by re-assigning that back to x, you get an x at the end of the function call that is not equal to the int(res) when you make the final comparison to get your boolean:

```
if int(res) == x:
```

A simple solution is to just not assign the temporary string that is created from the parameter x back to itself, and rather to just merge the first and second lines of your function into one:

```
lst = list(str(x))
```